# MySQL - How to use a variable as column name

Tags: mysql, variables, dynamic

I want to use a registry as a column name but the registry is variable and I don't know when it changes.

Example:

```
Config (field) = 'Medicine'
FieldContent (another field) = 'Remedy name'
```

A want to make this:

Medicine (use content of Config as column name) = 'Remedy Name' (as registry)

What have I tried?

```
SET @CONFIG = SELECT CONFIG;

SELECT FIELDCONTENT AS @CONFIG FROM TABLENAME;
```

MySql says that I can't use a variable as column name. There's other way?

actual  Config  Content
    Medicine RemedyName

Wanted  Medicine
    RemedyName

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My idea is to use a prepared statement:

```
SET @config := (SELECT CONFIG FROM yourtable WHERE id=1);
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT FIELDCONTENT AS `', @config, '` FROM TABLENAME');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```