# Define column as variable

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4f6fdf488a7093a697bd65fd051ce06e)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customer VARCHAR(255),
    product VARCHAR(255),
    sales_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(customer, product, sales_quantity)
VALUES 
("Customer_A", "Product_01", "100"),
("Customer_B", "Product_03", "970"),
("Customer_B", "Product_04", "730"),
("Customer_C", "Product_02", "480"),
("Customer_D", "Prodcut_01", "320");
```

**Query:**

```
SET
@selected_column = customer;

SELECT
@selected_column
FROM sales_local
GROUP BY 1;
```

---

In the query I want to have the flexiblity to change between the columns `customer` and `product`. 
Therefore, my idea was to declare them as variable. 
However, with this I get error `Unknown column 'customer' in 'field list'`.

Is it possible to declare a column as variable or is there any other similar solution for it?

---

*I know in the simple table above I could achieve this by just changing `customer` to `product` within the `SELECT` part. 

However, in my orignal file I use multiple `SELECT` statements that are binded with `UNION ALL` and I do not want to change the column name in each of those statement.*

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949624/mysql-select-query-with-variable-column-name

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019484/mysql-how-to-use-a-variable-as-column-name

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112609/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-column-name-for-a-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

You really need dynamic SQL for something like this.  Using MySQL prepared statements, we can try:

```sql
SET @selected_column = 'customer';
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT_WS(' ', 'SELECT', @selected_column, 'FROM sales_local GROUP BY 1')
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: `@selected_column` => `sys.quote_identifier(@selected_column)` At least lets try to protect it a bit against SQL Injection

Comment: @LukaszSzozda This isn't something which would be touched from outside Workbench or the command line.  If the OP really wants dynamic columns, they should have separate statements for the various queries then want to run.